# How does mysql handle select for update for non-existing row

Tags: mysql, go, innodb, deadlock, database-deadlocks

In our current application, we use a pattern that we select from a table using the primary key, if it doesn't return data, we insert a new row to it. And when we do the select we use a transaction and use a "select for update" statement.

What we found that is some times, the insert operation will have a deadlock. I highly suspect that is due to the first "select for update" didn't return any rows. That's why I am trying to ask, if we use select for update, and we use a primary key which doesn't exist, what rows will be locked? Is the whole table locked?

we use Golang and github.com/jmoiron/sqlx and github.com/volatiletech/sqlboiler for DB operation. but the pseudo code is:

```
// Creation API
func handle_create_request(payload) {
   id = gen_new_id()
   dao_upsert(id, payload)
}

// for Creation API and Update API
func dao_upsert(id, payload) {
  tx = start_db_transaction()
  record = select_for_update(id, tx)
  if record == nil {
     record = gen_new_record(id, payload)
     upsert_record(record, tx) // <--- Error throws: Error 1213: Deadlock 
found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
  }
  finalize_transaction(tx)
}
```

our database version by doing `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%version%';`

```
'aurora_version', '2.04.4'
'innodb_version', '5.7.12'
'protocol_version', '10'
'slave_type_conversions', ''
'tls_version', 'TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2'
'version', '5.7.12'
'version_comment', 'MySQL Community Server (GPL)'
'version_compile_machine', 'x86_64'
'version_compile_os', 'Linux'
```

Comment: found an interesting article, might be related https://mysqlquicksand.wordpress.com/2019/12/20/select-for-update-on-non-existent-rows/

Comment: good question, we use GoLang and https://github.com/volatiletech/sqlboiler @Progman

Answer (score 0):

This ist not a Anwser, its only to long for a comment.

The InnoDB Engine is row based lock, but i cant see the creation of the table.
After a dedlock you can look which tasks are gives you a deadlock.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show engine innodb status;
+--------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Type   | Name | Status                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
+--------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| InnoDB |      |
=====================================
2020-10-07 19:05:49 7fcf12830700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 34 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 8 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 1766546 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 1766306
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 29
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 27
Mutex spin waits 43, rounds 1290, OS waits 12
RW-shared spins 17, rounds 510, OS waits 17
RW-excl spins 0, rounds 0, OS waits 0
Spin rounds per wait: 30.00 mutex, 30.00 RW-shared, 0.00 RW-excl
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2020-09-17 09:58:49 7fcf12862700 Error in foreign key constraint of table `bernd`.`table_b`:
Create  table `bernd`.`table_b` with foreign key constraint failed. Referenced table `bernd`.`table_a` not found in the data dictionary near ' FOREIGN KEY (table_a_id) REFERENCES table_a (id) )'.
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 6201
Purge done for trx's n:o < 6196 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 37
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 0, not started
MySQL thread id 63, OS thread handle 0x7fcf12830700, query id 279 localhost root init
show engine innodb status
---TRANSACTION 6147, not started
MySQL thread id 1, OS thread handle 0x7fcf12894700, query id 0 Waiting for requests
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for completed aio requests (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for completed aio requests (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 ibuf aio reads: 0, log i/o's: 0, sync i/o's: 0
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
374 OS file reads, 156 OS file writes, 80 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 0.00 writes/s, 0.00 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 0, seg size 2, 0 merges
merged operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
discarded operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
0.00 hash searches/s, 0.00 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 149277494
Log flushed up to   149277494
Pages flushed up to 149277494
Last checkpoint at  149277494
Max checkpoint age    80826164
Checkpoint age target 78300347
Modified age          0
Checkpoint age        0
0 pending log writes, 0 pending chkp writes
39 log i/o's done, 0.00 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total memory allocated 140574720; in additional pool allocated 0
Total memory allocated by read views 104
Internal hash tables (constant factor + variable factor)
    Adaptive hash index 2217568         (2213368 + 4200)
    Page hash           139112 (buffer pool 0 only)
    Dictionary cache    632352  (554768 + 77584)
    File system         830352  (812272 + 18080)
    Lock system         333592  (332872 + 720)
    Recovery system     0       (0 + 0)
Dictionary memory allocated 77584
Buffer pool size        8191
Buffer pool size, bytes 134201344
Free buffers            7825
Database pages          366
Old database pages      0
Modified db pages       0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 346, created 20, written 102
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 366, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
0 read views open inside InnoDB
0 RW transactions active inside InnoDB
0 RO transactions active inside InnoDB
0 out of 1000 descriptors used
Main thread process no. 113887, id 140526766503680, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 10, updated 0, deleted 0, read 10
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
Number of system rows inserted 0, updated 0, deleted 0, read 0
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
 |
+--------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

I am not sure what you want to create or update, but normaly you can do it with one statemant. if any unique key exsists the next statement will update a record else it insert one.

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=VALUES(a)+VALUES(b);
```

[see mariadb Manual](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insert-on-duplicate-key-update/)

Comment: `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is not safe if you have mora than 1 PRIMARY/UNIQUE key in your table. (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).